# Retrieve Friends Username

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FBFriendPickerViewController to show all my friends, and then when i select one (multipleselection disabled) i want to get his name and username.

Could someone explain me why the name of the user returns right and the username returns null?

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {
    for (id<FBGraphUser> friend in self.friendPickerController.selection) {
        NSLog(@"%@", friend.name);
        NSLog(@"%@", friend.username);
    }
}
```

Which is the best way to retrieve my friends username?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**friend.id works right?**

```
Just get the JSON from graph.facebook.com/<friend.id>
```

^there will be a username key here

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
- (BOOL)friendPickerViewController:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
                 shouldIncludeUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    if (self.searchText && ![self.searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSRange result = [user.name
                          rangeOfString:self.searchText
                          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (result.location != NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, i don't want a search. I want to retrieve the username of the friend selected on the picker.